# QFile can't delete files on C drive

Tags: qt

I have a listWidget that displays files. I can delete selected files on the desktop and other locations, but files on the C drive will not delete. How can I delete the files on C drive? I am only trying to delete single files, not a directory. I am using Windows.  Here is my code snippet.

```
 void MainWindow::on_removeSelectedFile_clicked() {

   QString fileToRemove = ui->listWidget->currentItem()->text();

 QFile::setPermissions(ui->listWidget->currentItem()->text(), 
 QFile::ReadOwner|QFile::WriteOwner|QFile::ExeOwner);

 QFile::remove(fileToRemove);
 ui->listWidget->takeItem(ui->listWidget->currentRow());
}
```

I have tried setting all of the different permissions.
I have also tried using code below but not sure if I was doing the right thing with it:

```
extern Q_CORE_EXPORT int qt_ntfs_permission_lookup;
qt_ntfs_permission_lookup++;
```

How can I delete files on the C drive of have permission to delete any file in any location?

Comment: Are you running the program as administrator?

Comment: Where are you right-clicking? are you using Qt Creator?

Comment: What say 'QFile::errorString()'?

Comment: It says "Access is denied.\r\n"

Comment: If I start Qt as administrator, I am able to delete the files. However, I'm not sure what will happen when I deploy the program.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get this working, I needed administrator privileges when the program starts. Here is the solution.

1) Create the rc file :Open notepad and paste the following text inside then save the file as yourappname.rc This creates the rc file. Put the file in the folder that has all of your sourcecode and pro file.

```
#include <windows.h>
CREATEPROCESS_MANIFEST_RESOURCE_ID RT_MANIFEST "yourappname.exe.manifest"
```

2) Create the manifest file with notepad, paste the following text, and save it as yourappname.exe.manifest and put it in the same location as above.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <assemblyIdentity version="2.0.0.0" processorArchitecture="X86"
  name="yourappname.yourappname" type="win32" />
  <description>A discription of your app</description>
  <dependency />
  <!-- Identify the application security requirements. -->
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel
          level="requireAdministrator"
          uiAccess="false"/>
        </requestedPrivileges>
       </security>
   </trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

3) In your pro file put the following text:

```
win32 {
    RC_FILE = yourappname.rc
}
```

That's it. Now your application should start with administrator privileges.

There are similar post that describe this process too. Just make sure there are no spaces in your folder names or it won't work. Also you MUST run qt with administrator privileges for it to work. Right click Qt and run as administrator before trying to compile.